# problem with finding a folder

Tags: directory, windows-10

I'm beginner in c programming and started using ubuntu in windows 10. I created a folder name cass and make a notepad++ inside it. now when I want to reach the file by typing the code I receive the error. could you please help me?

```
cd/mnt/c/cass
```

bash: no such file or directory

Answer (score 3):

Please change this

```
cd/mnt/c/cass
```

to this

```
cd /mnt/c/cass
```

You need to have a **space** between the command **cd** and the path argument **/mnt/c/cass/**